# Cannot git-clone an OpenShift application

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I just opened an OpenShift account, and went through this tutorial:

https://www.openshift.com/blogs/any-version-of-nodejs-you-want-in-the-cloud-openshift-does-it-paas-style

When I got to creating the app, I got the following error:

```
erelsgl@erelsgl-H61MLC:~/mynode$ sudo rhc create-app mynode nodejs-0.6
Application Options
-------------------
  Namespace:  erel
  Cartridges: nodejs-0.6
  Gear Size:  default
  Scaling:    no

Creating application 'mynode' ... done


Waiting for your DNS name to be available ... done

Cloning into 'mynode'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '23.22.156.99' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Unable to clone your repository. Called Git with: git clone
ssh://522c....@mynode-erel.rhcloud.com/~/git/mynode.git/ "mynode"

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
WARNING:  Your application was created successfully but had problems during
          configuration. Below is a list of the issues and steps you can
          take to complete the configuration of your application.

  Application URL: http://mynode-erel.rhcloud.com/

  Issues:
    1. We were unable to clone your application's git repo - Unable to clone your repository.
Called Git with: git clone
ssh://522c...@mynode-erel.rhcloud.com/~/git/mynode.git/ "mynode"

  Steps to complete your configuration:
    1. Clone your git repo
      $ rhc git-clone mynode

  If you continue to experience problems after completing these steps,
  you can try destroying and recreating the application:

    $ rhc app delete mynode --confirm

  Please contact us if you are unable to successfully create your
  application:

    Support - https://www.openshift.com/support

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!



Your application 'mynode' is now available.

  URL:        http://mynode-erel.rhcloud.com/
  SSH to:     522c....@mynode-erel.rhcloud.com
  Git remote: ssh://522c....@mynode-erel.rhcloud.com/~/git/mynode.git/

Run 'rhc show-app mynode' for more details about your app.
```

I tried to clone, and got this:

```
erelsgl@erelsgl-H61MLC:~/mynode$ sudo rhc git-clone mynode
Cloning into 'mynode'...
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Unable to clone your repository. Called Git with: git clone
ssh://522c....@mynode-erel.rhcloud.com/~/git/mynode.git/ "mynode"
```

EDIT: I have an ssh key:

```
erelsgl@erelsgl-H61MLC:~/mynode$ sudo rhc sshkey list
default (type: ssh-rsa)
-----------------------
Fingerprint: 62:...

You have 1 SSH keys associated with your account.
```

Answer (score 6):

I got exactly the same issue and found the solution, under windows. It seems you are under Linux, but may be this will give you ideas.

First you need to make sure your SSL keys have been created properly for Git (check this [post](http://technotes.tostaky.biz/2013/01/generating-ssh-keys-for-tortoisegit.html) on my blog for instructions).

Then, using Git for Windows, right click on the folder to clone the project and enter the SSL URL:

[image]

Make sure you check `Load Putty Key` and select the path to your `.ppk` file. This worked like a charm for me.

May be you need to specify the path to your private key file under Linux when cloning from the command line.

Comment: Strange thing, I do not want to install another program (here Tortoise) on windows.It should work on the cmd, git should find the .ssh folder and should look up automatically the ppk or private key or whatever.

Comment: again me.In the webconsole my key name is "tommueller" and not "default". Could this be an issue? BTW, the ppk file used while git makes sense because you need a ppk while "ssh"ing (ssh works for me)

Comment: I tried to use the git clone cmd when right clicking the folder for tortoise git. But there is no git clone , but many others. Furthermore, does tortoise also provide the "load putty key" when I commit?

Comment: Git Friends, this might help us!!https://www.openshift.com/blogs/accessing-your-code-for-your-openshift-application-via-windows-explorer-using-tortoisegit

Answer (score 5):

Your mistake is you are clone the repository inside app's host, this goes to clone your repository inside your application host on openshift, then it gives you a permission denied to write access on host, you must close it in your local.

First Open a Command Prompt, then type:

```
mkdir apprepo
cd /d apprepo
git clone ssh://522c....@mynode-erel.rhcloud.com/~/git/mynode.git/
```

and if you have any changes in repository:

```
git commit -a
git push
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are having issues with your ssh key. Have you added one to openshift? You can run `rhc sshkey list` to check. Make sure that one of these private keys is in your ssh folder, `C:\user\\[username]\\.ssh\` for windows and `~/.ssh` on linux (Note that on both os's they are hidden folders). Openshift refuses to let you do anything with the git repo unless it can verify your ssh key. Take a look at this [Openshift SSH Documentation](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/dive-into-openshift-with-ssh) for more details.

Comment: I have a single ssh key (see the edit to my question). How can I check if it is in my ssh folder? My ssh folder (on Linux) contains 3 files: id_rsa, id_rsa.pub, and known_hosts. Non of them contains a fingerprint..

Comment: try *rhc sshkey add*. If you still are getting errors after trying this, open up your id_rsa.pub file and copy it. Paste it into the public key section of https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/keys/new to add your current public ssh key into openshift.

Comment: I opened the console, and found out that my public key is already there (under the name "default")... probably there is some other problem.

Comment: I still think it is ssh problem. The fact that the server denied your git push means that something ssh related is not lining up. Here is a openshift documentation page for your permission denied error that I found. https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1015-how-to-resolve-permission-denied-errors-permission-denied-publickeygssapi-keyexgssapi-wi

Answer (score 1):

go to preference in eclipse and in ssh key menu, click KEY MANAGEMENT and ther is a rsa key tab click that and copy your public key and click the button save as private key... then go to your open shift application and paste your public key and work  on it... i hope it working

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sudo` when creating your app or when using `rhc`

Comment: try creating the app inside a folder where you have write permissions.  The `rhc` command will attempt to create a local git repository for you to work with.  You can disable this behavior by using the `--no-git` flag.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the thread for answering SSH key related issues, even if the answer relating to not cloning on the host machine seems to make the most sense.

Regarding the configured keys being good for opening an SSH connection but not for git cloning, I tried everything in this thread and on the OpenShift site and eventually discovered that Git for Windows wasn't using the SSH keys managed by Pageant; the only way for me to clone my repository was to have the Git GUI generate a new key for me and then add that one's public key to my OpenShift application as well.

I'm posting this answer here because I don't know where else I should, I hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you, and got an idea based on ʀɣαɳĵ answer

> Don't use sudo when creating your app or when using rhc

Considering this recommendation I tried deleting my app and re-creating it using my user without using sudo, but I received some permission errors indicating problems accessing: 
- **.openshift** folder under my user home folder 
- **.ssh/rsa*** documents under my user home folder also
- **My actual directory** where a new directory would be created as part of the app creation

After granting access to those resources using chmod: 
- **chmod 755** for both .openshift and .ssh/rsa* 
- **chmod -R 777 mydir** in my actual directory

I re created the app (rhc create app *yourAppName platform* ) and everything is working fine now!

Hope it helps you.