# Can't git clone OpenShift with NetBeans

Tags: git, netbeans, openshift

Have created application on OpenShift. And now I want connect Netbeans to it. I try clone git by this method

Team --> Clone

In 'Repository URL' field as 'SSH' I enter my SSH URL. Look like ' ssh://538fe7ea50044609120003ef@myapp-masakra.rhcloud.com/~/git/myapp.git/ '

In 'username' field I enter my OpenShift application login;

And I enter my Private SSH Path into appropriate field.

[image]

but I get the error:

Incorrect credentials for repository at ssh://538fe7ea50044609120003ef@myapp-masakra.rhcloud.com/~/git/myapp.git/

what is the problem??

Comment: I made clone 'myapp' from OpenShift on my HD too. Maybe I have to work with that repositorium??

Comment: If you cloned it on your hard drive, what `git remote -v` returns for that clone?

Comment: resolved: I used 'git init' in ../myapp on HD then just opened this folder as project in NetBeans. After editing project in NetBeans from command line i wrote 'git add .' 'git commit -m' 'git push'. Thank you all

Comment: Ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

The [OP user3491167](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3491167/user3491167) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095591/cant-git-clone-openshift-with-netbeans#comment37165485_24095591):

> I used '`git init`' in `../myapp` on HD, then just opened this folder as project in NetBeans.
>   After editing project in NetBeans from command line, I wrote

```
git add .
git commit -m 
git push
```

In other words, before connecting a remote repo, you need to have one locally.

---

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18685556/6309), make sure you did add your public key to the OpenShift server (using the [`rhc` command](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_user_guide.html)).

```
rhc sshkey list
```

Or “OpenShift Management Console” -> “My Account” -> “Public Keys” on the right side (as in this [blog post](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/dive-into-openshift-with-ssh)):

[image: https://www.openshift.com/sites/default/files/sshkeys_web.png]

Answer (score -1):

Use Pageant.exe Putty. Double click to open it. once opened the icon will be displayed on the TaskBar. Click the right mouse button on the icon and select Add Key, select the correct *.ppk and put the passphrase.

Once this is done Netbeans be ready to recognize authentication and could do Push and Clone.